# Burnside's formula on a hexagon

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I was trying to use Burnside's formula on a regular hexagon. I believe the answer is $13$, but I am trying to show my work. Here is what I have figured out.

$$\frac{1}{12}(2^6 + 36 + 30 + \cdots?)$$

$2^6$ is $D_{6}$ (at least that is what I think the regular hexagon is called). Then I reflected over the vertices. This gave me $3$ different possible reflections with $12$ different possible ways which is $36$. Then I reflected over the midpoints. This gave me $3$ different possible reflections with $10$ different possible ways which is $30$. Now the rotations are a bit confusing to me.

Comment: I recommend looking at John B. Fraleigh - A First Course in Abstract Algebra

Comment: which fix(x) is $2^6$?

Comment: I think we need more detail in what you mean by using Burnside's formula on a regular hexagon, as there's more than one way to use Burnside's formula on a hexagon

Comment: I doubt you're talking about the case of counting hexagonal tiles with three black vertices and three white vertices, but this is one way to use Burnside's formula on a hexagon. In which case are you being told to use it?

Comment: Well upon looking at a previous example, they use Burnsides formula on a triangle, and they are taking the sum of #fix(g) which is the number of fixed color labels under g. Using burnsides formula we ended up geting an answer of 4 different kinds of colorings.

Comment: That was the answer, but what was the question?! Burnside's formula always takes the sum of fix(g), but it can be applied to answer various different questions. g can be defined in different ways you see

Comment: Thats pretty much all we are doing which is finding how many different kinds of colorings can be done one each regular polygon.

Comment: Ok I think I get it.  The question is how many different ways are there to color the vertices of the given polygon

Comment: But could you pray tell us what are you trying to count. Burnside's formula has been used on this site to count many things.

Comment: Yeah, actually, i've still not got it

Comment: Yes you are right bluesh34. The asks for how many different ways are there to color the vertices of a given polygon. In particular, a regular hexagon. Now that we have established what I mean, are the numbers I have so far correct? Also, I am unsure of the rotations.

Comment: By how many colors? Two? Please edit the question, so that interested members don't need to read the fine print :-)

Comment: Is it how many ways to colour the vertices of a polygon so that no 2 adjacent vertices are coloured the same?

Comment: Sorry if I appear rude, but it's been a while since I've considered such problems, so I like to make sure I've understood the question before I try to answer it

Comment: I got 13, but the question is then "How many ways there are to color the hexagon in two colors, if we consider two colorings gotten from each other by rotating or reflecting the hexagon the same?" Nothing about adjacent vertices.

Comment: If adjacent vertices must have distinct colors, aren't the only possibilities thean BWBWBW and WBWBWB and it is a matter of taste/definition, whether you call those distinct. Burnside's theorem doesn't enter the solution at all in that case. So once more: What is the question? Edit it into the question body, please. Don't reply by a comment.

Comment: Hopefully this will help. Let me start with the triangle again. Now color the vertices black or white. They can not be all the same color and in this case, you will have either 2 white vertices and 1 black one, or 2 black vertices and 1 white one. Once you have established that, you start counting. How many different colorings can be made. The answer is 4. Now apply this to a hexagon. If this is not clear enough I apologize.

Comment: I think the question could be you've got 6 colours. How many different ways are there of colouring the vertices of the hexagon wihtout 2 adjacent vertices being coloured the same?

Comment: Not sure you need Burnside's formula for this though: it just seems like $2^5 = 32$, but that's not to say you can't use Burnside's lemma: it's just a much longer method

Comment: Sorry, i'm struggling with this. It's not difficult when you know what you're doing, i know, but I've forgotten

Comment: no worries. the effort is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I agree with the $\frac{1}{12}$ but I'm not getting fix(g). I know we've got $Sx$ is the set of all permutations of a non-empty set $X$, $\alpha$ is a permutation in $Sx$ and $fix(\alpha) = (x\varepsilon X|\alpha(x) = x)$, so I need to know what X is

Comment: I get that $Sx$ is the permutations which are the 6 rotations and the 6 reflections

Comment: But where does the different ways of ordering 6 colours come in?

Comment: the answer's here http://people.math.sfu.ca/~jtmulhol/math302/notes/23-Burnside.pdf

Comment: maybe this would help. The formula for Burnsides Formula I have written is $\frac{1}{G} \sum fix(g)$ where $g \in G$ and $G$ is the group of symmetries.

Comment: Mick, I still didn't understand how you got four colorings of a triangle with B & W. You seemed to disallow monocolor cases, didn't you? Then there three ways to color the triangle with two blacks and a single white, namely BBW, BWB, WBB. Because you are talking about rotational symmetries, I assume that you treat all these as the same coloring as they can be gotten from each other by rotating. The same with two whites and a single black. So that give only 2 colorings. Can't get to 4, if the monocolor ones are excluded.

Answer (score 10):

The action on the dihedral group on the hexagon is illustrated below:

[image: Dihedral group on the hexagon]

The number of assignments of $2$ colors to the vertices that are preserved by a group element $\alpha$ is $$2^{\text{Number of vertex orbits under } \langle \alpha \rangle}$$ since each vertex orbit can be assigned any color, and every vertex in any orbit must be colored the same.

The vertex orbits are highlighted below corresponding to the group elements above (vertices in the same orbit are assigned the same color):

[image: Vertex orbits]

Inputting this into [Burnside's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) gives the number of assignments of $2$ colors (inequivalent under rotations and reflections) as
$$\tfrac{1}{12}(2^6 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^3 + 2^4 + 2^3 + 2^4 + 2^3 + 2^4)=13.$$

Precisely two of these inequivalent assignments of $2$ colors have all colours the same: when they're all white, and when they're all black.  That leaves $11$ inequivalent assignments of $2$ colors to the vertices where both colors are used.

Comment: Consider rotation through $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. You said there are $2^2$ 'assignments of 2 colors to the vertices [preserved in this case]... since each vertex orbit can be assigned any color, and every vertex in any orbit must be colored the same'. Whilst this is true, this is not the number of *inequivalent* assignments, since coluring all the vertices in one orbit white is equivalent to colouring all the vertices in the other orbit black, so the number of *inequivalent* assignments of 2 colours to the vertices preserved by rotation through $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ is actually 2 rather than $2^2 = 4$

Comment: Actually, I can see now that you do only have 2 in your final answer, as you subtract 2  (the ones with all colours the same) from every case

Comment: Where did you get these diagrams/how did you make them? I found them very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I upvoted the first answer but I would like to show how to compute the
cycle index $Z(D_6)$  of the dihedral group $D_6$  and apply the Polya
Enumeration Theorem to this problem.

We  need  to  enumerate   and  factor  the  twelve  permutations  that
contribute to $Z(D_6).$

There is the idenity, which contributes
$$a_1^6.$$
The two rotations by a distance of one and five contribute
$$2 a_6.$$
The two rotations by a distance of two or four contribute
$$2 a_3^2.$$
Finally the rotation by a distance of three contributes
$$a_2^3.$$

There  are three reflections  about an  axis passing  through opposite
vertices, giving
$$3 a_1^2 a_2^2$$

and three reflections  about an axis passing through  the midpoints of
opposite edges, giving
$$3 a_2^3.$$

This finally yields the cycle index
$$Z(D_6) = \frac{1}{12}
\left(a_1^6 + 2a_6 + 2a_3^2 + 3a_1^2 a_2^2 + 4a_2^3\right).$$

Coloring the hexagon with at most two colors we get
$$Z(D_6)(A+B)_{A=1, B=1}.$$

This yields
$$\frac{1}{12}
\left(2^6 + 2\times 2 + 2\times 2^2 
+ 3\times 2^2 \times 2^2 + 4 \times 2^3\right)$$
which evaluates to
$$13.$$

There is a list of similar computations at
[MSE Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions#13335).