# Burnside's Lemma on regular octagon

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

> A *3-coloring* of a regular octagon is a choice of one of the colors
>   red, blue or green for each of its eight vertices. We consider two
>   3-colorings to be the same if we can get from one to the other via an
>   isometry of the octagon. Use Burnside's Lemma to find the number of
>   different 3-colorings of the octagon.

So a regular octagon is $D_8$. Working from the logic in [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485081/burnsides-formula-on-a-hexagon) I got the following:

$\frac{1}{16}(3^8+3^1+3^2+3^3+3^4+3^3+3^2+3^1+3^4+3^6+3^5+3^6+3^5+3^6)=\frac{4737}{8}$ 
This is obviously incorrect as it's not an integer. Where did I go wrong in my calculations of possible permutations of rotations?

Comment: Well, you only have 14 terms and you should have 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the elments of $D_8=\{(-1)^m \theta^n \forall m,n \}$, where $\theta$ denotes rotation by $2\pi/8$ (i.e. it's the 8th root of $-1$).

Here is how I count the orbits -

$1:3^8, \theta: 3^1, \theta^2: 3^2, \theta^3: 3^1, \theta^4: 3^4, \theta^5: 3^1, \theta^6: 3^2, \theta^7: 3^1$

$-1: 3^5, -\theta: 3^4, -\theta^2:3^5, -\theta^3: 3^4,  -\theta^4: 3^5, -\theta^5: 3^4, -\theta^6: 3^5, -\theta^7: 3^4$

So Burnside Lemma gives
$\frac{1}{16}(3^8+3^1+3^2+3^1+3^4+3^1+3^2+3^1+3^5+3^4+3^5+3^4+3^5+3^4+3^5+3^4)=498$.

---

Upon further inspection, here are a few of the terms that differ -

If you rotate by $3\theta$, you only have one choice of color, not 3.

And in no reflection it is possible to assign 6 different colors independently, all reflections give you 5 or 4. You can see this by drawing lines which connect reflected points to each other on an octagon.