# Coloring the vertices of a decagon

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, group-actions, fixed-point-theorems

> In how many ways can you color, up to symmetry, the vertices of a regular decagon using $q$ colors?

(We are talking here about the dihedral group of order $20$).

So I was thinking about maybe group actions, thinking about it as orbits... But I really couldn't get to anything.

I understand that I should use Burnside lemma to calculate the fixed points size which is the answer.

What I can't see is what are the fixed points for that group action?

Obviously it would be the symmetries where the coloring remains the same, and yet I'm not sure how to do that...

Comment: I've flagged this question as being a repost of [a deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2865561). Please do not delete and repost questions.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485081/burnsides-formula-on-a-hexagon for a fully worked out case of the hexagon, the logic of which you can apply to the decagon